# Why are these questions closed?

Tags: discussion

1. [Did Charlie Hebdo ever publish any cartoon satirizing Judaism?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15757/did-charlie-hebdo-ever-publish-any-cartoon-satirizing-judaism)
2. [What is the status of Kashmir in the eyes of USA and EU?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/what-is-the-status-of-kashmir-in-the-eyes-of-usa-and-eu)
3. [Why is it okay for the USA if Greece deploys S300PMU-1 but it is not okay if Turkey deploys S400?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24926/why-is-it-okay-for-the-usa-if-greece-deploys-s300pmu-1-but-it-is-not-okay-if-tur)

Comment: I think the explanations in the close notifications are good enough. If you disagree, please take the time to explain why that is. How is any of these questions in line with the community's guidelines?

Comment: I think the Charlie Hebdo question is okay btw. There are many similar questions about the media. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker perhaps you would like to weigh in on a [question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/is-the-media-on-topic) I had on that the other month.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the status of Kashmir in the eyes of USA and EU?

This was closed as Too Broad.  Probably partly because it names two regions.  One of which (EU) doesn't actually have an official view on status, as it isn't a diplomatic union but a trade union.  The other problem is that

> Do they consider the movement in Kashmir as terrorism, or a movement of a large chunk of the Muslim population who want to separate from India?

asks a different question from the title.  Now instead of asking about the status of Kashmir, a geographic region, it is asking about something else that it doesn't define particularly well.  Which movement?  As stands, this could be talking about any Kashmiran separatist movement.  Again, Too Broad.

The question could also be closed for being Unclear what you're asking.

> Did Charlie Hebdo ever publish any cartoon satirizing Judaism?

and

> Why is it okay for the USA if Greece deploys S300PMU-1 but it is not okay if Turkey deploys S400?

Are both written in rather ranty tones.  The Greece/Turkey one seems to have a clear agenda of calling out the US for inconsistency.  It's especially bad, since the first link explains what's different now from then:  Russia is under sanctions now and wasn't then.  In general, your citations should support your question, not debunk it.

The Charlie Hebdo question is about trivia surrounding a magazine that makes political commentary.  Added to its ranty nature, I'm unsurprised that some people didn't find it a political question.  It's an offputting way to frame the question.  I suppose it could have been worse, "Hey dead people, why didn't you spend more of your time on making fun of Jews?  Wonder if you might be alive today if you had?"  But of course, some people will read it that way.

In general, if you are looking to have more open, upvoted questions:

1. Consider tightening your definition of politics, as the Charlie Hebdo question dances along the line.
2. Write in more neutral tones.  Your questions tend to read as "I had this opinion, am I right?"
3. Think about how the question will be perceived by readers.  Make sure that the question is clear and easy to understand.  The title and the body should both be about the same question.
4. Write out what you actually want to know.